# what is difference between sonar checkstyle plugin and eclipse checkstyle plugin. are they same?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, checkstyle

I have a project specific cusotmized eclipse checkstyle plugin and i would like to use the same plugin in sonar as well. can some help me how to proceed for the same.

Comment: @RC i am looking for using customized checkstyle eclipse plugin(which i already have) to use in sonar.

Comment: This is not a duplicate! You must basically provide an XML config file which you put into extensions/rules/checkstyle along with your custom JAR. See example [here](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/blob/master/plugins/sonar-checkstyle-extension-plugin/src/main/resources/org/sonar/examples/checkstyle/checkstyle-extensions.xml). Sorry, I cannot post a longer explanation b/c this question was closed.